# echo breaking on cyrillic symbol

Tags: php, echo

i want to echo $html variable (which contents html code of page) to browser in my php script. but if my $html has cyrillic symbol echo is breaking on it symbol - all before this symbol is on page - but all next is empty, what reason can it be?

Comment: Have you tried to change the encoding of the html code to UTF-8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The character encoding of the value of `$html` does not suit the character encoding you declare your output with. You need to identify the character encoding of `$html` and make sure to properly declare your output to be encoded with it.

The best way to do that is the [HTTP header](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.2). You can do that with [`header`](http://php.net/header):

```
header('Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8');
```

This declares the content to be HTML encoded with UTF-8.

Besides that, PHP and the web server have default character encodings that are sent if no other was specified. In PHP, the default character encoding is specified by [*default_charset*](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.default-charset); and as for Apache web server, it is specified by [`AddDefaultCharset`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#adddefaultcharset).