# Arabic being displayed in giberish and question marks

Tags: php, mysql, unicode, arabic

I created a php website that would simply load the text from a mysql database, when I open it in a browser the Arabic text is presented in gibberish but then when I change the encoding of my browser to UTF-8 it's displayed properly, how can I force the encoding to be UTF-8 so users don't have to change it?

The menu part of the website which also loads the menu items from the same database (different table, they both have the same coalition "utf8_unicode_ci") but they are all displayed as question marks. How can I fix this?

You can check out the website on test.bdsfilmfest.com

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Chk this Question and answered by Gumbo http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3667531/echo-breaking-on-cyrillic-symbol

Comment: The data in the menu are actually question mark characters (U+003F). This is probably the result of a character set conversion where the target character set does not have the characters. How do you process that data from the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your web server probably sends a `iso-8859-1` content-type header by default.

Either change the web server's behaviour - it should be possible to do a

```
 AddDefaultCharset utf-8
```

in a `.htaccess` file in the root directory of your web site.

or override the header from within PHP in each individual file:

```
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
```

Comment: It’s rather the client that falls back to ISO 8859-1 as there is no character encoding specified.

Comment: This fixed the text but the menu text is still being displayed as question marks :S Thank you very much though :)

Comment: @yousef is the database connection you use also encoded in UTF-8? Try a `SET NAMES utf8;` before making any queries

Comment: It worked! the connection was not UTF-8 encoded. This is great :)

Comment: AddDefaultCharset is a bad idea. If the document has a meta element signaling it has another encoding, the meta element will be ignored. It also prevents the browser from content-sniffing the document.

Answer (score 0):

The most easy way is to set the [default_charset](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php) somewhere (possibly in apache vhost conf, in php.ini, or .htaccess file), so you won't have to repeat sending correct headers each & every script.

Answer (score 0):

Uncomment this:

```
<!--<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />!-->
```